# Dynamically Updating Controls ASP.Net and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot for the life of me work out how to update bootstrap controls with ASP.Net.

I have the following code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title Mark Hub</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <script>
        var url = "http://localhost:51520/api/teacher/"

        function getTerms(course) {}
        //get a reference to the select element
        $select = $('#termSelect');
        //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "global/currentterms/" + course ,
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(data){
                //clear the current content of the select
                $select.html('');
                //iterate over the data and append a select option
                $.each(data.person, function(key, val){
                    $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
                })
            },
            error:function(){
                //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                $select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Mark Hub", "Index", "Teacher", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Teacher", "Index", "Teacher")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 text-left">
                    <select class="form-control" id="courseSelect" onclick="getTerms()">
                        <option>DEC 10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 text-left">
                    <select class="form-control" id="termSelect">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <hr />
                    <footer>
                        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to take the value the user selects (I only have one for convenience at the moment) from the `courseSelect` control, pass it to my Javascript function `getTerms`, call a web api and populate the `termSelect` control dynamically from the returned `JSON`.

Selecting a value from my `courseSelect` combobox is not updating my `termSelect` combobox.

How would I fix my code?

**EDITED WITH UPDATE CODE TO REFLECT UPDATES IN ANSWERS**

```
<script>
    var url = "http://localhost:51520/api/teacher/"

    $(function(){
        $('#courseSelect').on('change',function(){
            // This is equal to your getTerms function
            var course =  $('#courseSelect').val();
            //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
            $.ajax({
                url: url + "global/currentterms/" + course,
                dataType:'JSON',
                success:function(data){
                    //clear the current content of the select
                    $select.html('');
                    //iterate over the data and append a select option
                    $.each(data.termID, function(key, val){
                        $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
                    })
                },
                error:function(){
                    //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                    $select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
                }
            })
        })});
</script>
```

My code still doesn't work and when I add a breakpoint in VS, the function isn't called on me selecting a value from the select box `courseSelect`.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Right now you are appending the Ajax result to `$('#courseSelect');` element and not to `termSelect`

Comment: @Reddy Fixed `courseSelect` to `termSelect`. @StephenMuecke updated question to better reflect problem.

Comment: You still have not defined the problem. Are you hitting your controller method? What is the controller method and what does it return? What if any errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: Now I see that you are not passing the selected value from the dropdown into your API call

Comment: @Reddy Thank you. I have fixed that in code, however, it is still not working.

Comment: @fluffybonkers I have given my answer.. you need little modifications in your current code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this function `getTerms()`  on click of the select tag.. which is wrong.. you must **use `on change` event** . Even click will work but then it will get trigerred even if you click the text box which will do a API call , this is unnecessary request .. Also **stop using inline event binder** it's deprecated and soon will stop working in future, you must **bind event using on in Jquery** change your code to below.

Remove the onClick in your HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="courseSelect">
    <option>DEC 10</option>
</select>
```

Then in Jquery use this

```
$(function(){
   $('#courseSelect').on('change',function(){
          // This is equal to your getTerms function
          var course =  $(this).val(); 
          // rest of your logic goes here 
   });
});
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your suggestion. My code still doesn't work.

Comment: @fluffybonkers You updated code looks fair enough. Only thing I can think about is the you have not removed the `onClick` in the select tag. Remove it and check. Also look into the browser console window to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I am getting two errors in the browser: http://localhost:51520/api/teacher/global/currentterms/DEC%2010. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54866' is therefore not allowed access.
Index:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: $select is not defined

Answer (score 0):

your javascript' function is `getTerms(course)`, while you are calling it on your click method as `getTerms()`

so you should change your `javascript` as following :

```
function getTerms() {}
        //get a reference to the select element
        $select = $('#termSelect');
        $course= $('#courseSelect').val(); // this is how you get the value of course
        //your next code
```